# Team City - Build times slow with a long lull after MSTest

Tags: performance, build, teamcity, mstest, dotcover

I'm currently running team city on my my build and lately it has been running quite a bit slower than normal. I've checked performance on the hardware and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Looking at the logs for the build there is a long time between running MSTest and DotCover. The MS Test themselves and the build only total 4 mins time, but then there's the long lag of 13 mins between 14:50 and 15:03 that happenshappens.

[image]

[image]

What could be causing this lull in time? Has anyone had this issue as well?

EDIT:
Also, looking at the logs what is the 2 service processes that team city is waiting on to complete?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that pops to mind in what you've posted is that the code coverage is taking a long time to complete.

Have you tried disabling the dotcover step to see if that is what is hanging the build? After all TeamCity is saying the unit tests alone take only about 3 mins.

If that's it then you might want to think about putting code coverage into a nightly and leave the CI build to only build and run unit tests. After all code coverage is not something you really need to gather for every single build you do but is useful to get a day to day snapshot of.